# Setting environment variables in cloud run or just put them in container file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

When using the Cloud Run, what is the most secure way to deploy secret such as API keys? Should I dump them in a file in my project or should I set them up as environment variables in Cloud Run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither in the container nor in the environment variable. Choose [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs) for this.

If you don't want to change your code, I [wrote a wrapper (and an article) to do this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secret-manager-improve-cloud-run-security-without-changing-the-code-634f60c541e6)